# What is wrong with parsing this time string for 'std::chrono'?

Tags: c++, parsing, c++-chrono

I simple want to parse a time-string to a `chrono::system_clock::time_point` using:

```c
#include <iosfwd>
#include "date/date.h"

std::stringstream ssTime;
ssTime << "17:34:05";
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp_time;
ssTime >> date::parse("%H:%M:%S", tp_time);
```

I expected to get the `time_point` of the specified time after `EPOCH`, but instead I get 0 (i.e. `EPOCH`).

Note, that I'm using the [**date** library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) of [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design of the `parse` function is that if you don't parse enough information for the type being parsed, the `failbit` is set on the stream.  `parse` considers the `{h, m, s}` information insufficient for uniquely determining an instant in time (a `system_clock::time_point`), so this parse fails.

You can make this work by parsing into a `seconds` duration instead:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    std::stringstream ssTime;
    ssTime << "17:34:05";
    std::chrono::seconds tp_time;
    ssTime >> date::parse("%H:%M:%S", tp_time);
}
```

`tp_time` will have the value of 63245s in this example.